# Firebase Storage Download getFile(Uri) with "content://" uri throws java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

My use case: Get content from remote only when local uri can't resolve the content.

1) File is available remotely in the Firebase storage with the following reference structure **user.uid/files/fileId**, example:

```
ysCwjgc0zGfUNuZimHGaun0MzlP2/files/document-d876e8aa-4b6a-45ed-b2f1-dfd2fbf21360
```

2) Local device determined the content is not available, attempts to get from Firebase Storage, using the same reference as above.

3) Local creates the file and getUri for the file like below:

```
// TEST
File f = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/pictures",fileId + ".jpg");
Log.e(LOG_TAG,"test local file created: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
Uri localUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY,f);
Log.e(LOG_TAG, "test local file content uri created: " + localUri.toString());
```

4) Tried to use localUri as argument for [getFile(android.net.Uri)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getFile(android.net.Uri)) to get file from Firebase:
but my cat screams the following IO exception.

```
E/FileRemoteDataSource: Local file not found, trying to fetch from remote...
E/FileRemoteDataSource: test local file created: /data/user/0/com.sample.app/files/pictures/document-d876e8aa-4b6a-45ed-b2f1-dfd2fbf21360.jpg
E/FileRemoteDataSource: test local file uri created: content://com.sample.app.fileprovider/pics/document-d876e8aa-4b6a-45ed-b2f1-dfd2fbf21360.jpg
E/FileDownloadTask: Exception occurred during file write.  Aborting.
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1000)
at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.zza(Unknown Source:75)
at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source:190)
```

5) Tries to use f as argument for [getFile(File)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getFile(java.io.File)) to get file from Firebase:
I can get the file perfectly fine, my cat is perfectly asleep with just...

```
E/FileRemoteDataSource: Local file not found, trying to fetch from remote...
E/FileRemoteDataSource: test local file created: /data/user/0/com.sample.app/files/pictures/document-d876e8aa-4b6a-45ed-b2f1-dfd2fbf21360.jpg
E/FileRemoteDataSource: test local file uri created: content://com.sample.app.fileprovider/pics/document-d876e8aa-4b6a-45ed-b2f1-dfd2fbf21360.jpg
// No exception, got file
```

Note: In my project I have file providing logic somewhere else, the above just a example case.I would prefer to work with content uri as much as I can, what am I doing wrong by using the content Uri? Thx.

**Additional Info:**

The Uri points to a file residing in app-internal directory, so storage read/write permissions are and should not be required.

I use Firebase to upload the file by its Uri and it was able to locate, read and upload the file perfectly. The same local uri that was provided by the android framework [FileProvider.getUriForFile(f)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)).The test file was uploaded successfully like this:

```
// putFile(uri) where uri references to a local file where to
// upload the file from.
UploadTask uploadTask = resourceRef.putFile(localUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase's getFile also suuports File as an argument, so you may want to try it instead